# Evaluate $\int_0^{+\infty } \frac{\log(t)}{1+t^2} \, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How can we compute $$I=\int_0^{+\infty } \frac{\log(t)}{1+t^2} \, dt$$
Mathematica gives $I=0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**

Write

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(t)}{1+t^2} \, dt=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(t)}{1+t^2} \, dt+\int_1^\infty \frac{\log(t)}{1+t^2} \, dt$$
and then change the variable $t=\frac1x$ for one of the two last integrals.

Comment: You were a busy man yesterday/today!